# Sed Pattern Match then Append to Line

Tags: sed, append

I have some lines down below and I'm trying to append "Check" to the line that starts with Apples. Does someone know how I can get "Check" on the same line as Apples, not a new one and print the output? I wasn't getting anywhere on my own.

Thanks

What I have:

```
Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Bananas Milk
```

What I want:

```
Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Bananas Milk Check
```

What I tried:

```
sed -i '/^Apples/a Check' file
```

What I got:

```
Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Bananas Milk
Check
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Apples/s/$/ check/' file
```

If a line contains `Apples` append the string  `check`. Where `$` represents an anchor that is the end of the line (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, on my end i had to add the -i flag to persist the file in the change:
sed -i '/Apples/s/$/ check/' file

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you `a`ppend the line with `a` command, see [this reference](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-40):

> The "a" command appends a line after the range or pattern.

What you want is a mere substitution. However, there may be some more tweaks you would like to implement, here are some suggestions:

```bash
sed -i 's/Apples/& Check/g' file           # Adds ' Check' after each 'Apples'
sed -i 's/\<Apples\>/& Check/g' file       # Only adds ' Check' after 'Apples' as whole word
sed -i -E 's/\<Apples(\s+Check)?\>/& Check/g' file # Adds ' Check' after removing existing ' Check'
```

Note these suggestions are **for GNU `sed` only**. `\<` and `\>` in GNU sed patterns are word boundaries, `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces in GNU `sed` POSIX ERE patterns, and  `-E` enables the POSIX ERE pattern syntax.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3AmApH):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Bananas Milk'
sed 's/Apples/& Check/g' <<< "$s"
sed 's/\<Apples\>/& Check/g' <<< "$s"
sed -E 's/\<Apples(\s+Check)?\>/& Check/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output in each case is:

```
Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Check Bananas Milk
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^Apples/s/.*/& Check/' input_file
Grocery store bank and hardware store
Apples Bananas Milk Check
```

You can match lines that begin with `Apples`, return it with `&` appending `Check`